# Distribute php loop values in columns

Tags: php, for-loop

I have table having 3 column says customer 1,customer 2 and customer 3, Having upper limit value like 200,300 and 500 total 1000.And i have 8 different values in an array like 150,150,150,150,100,100,100,50,50 and i have to distribute these values in to each customers as better as posible(dont cross limit).

I tried to make table before split

```
Before Split

<?php
$customer_count = 3;
$customer_limit = array('200','300','500');
$values_array = array('150','150','150','150','100','100','100','50','50')
?>

<table width="50%" border="1">

  <tr>
  <?php
    for($i=1;$i<=$customer_count;$i++){
        echo "<td>Customer ".$i."</td>";
    }
  ?>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <?php
    for($i=0;$i<$customer_count;$i++){
        echo "<td>".$customer_limit[$i]."</td>";
    }
  ?>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="1">


          <?php
          foreach($values_array as $val){
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?=$val;?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
          }
          ?>



        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
          <?php
          foreach($values_array as $val){
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?=$val;?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
          }
          ?>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
          <?php
          foreach($values_array as $val){
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?=$val;?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
          }
          ?>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

So i give me an idea how to make "after split" table like in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use so many loops here. My approach is a bit different, but it certainly solves the purpose.

We need a nested loop, one for the customers and one for the values.

First, we can loop through and store data in a variable called $customer, which stores data of all 3 customers with their respective distributed values(Keeping in mind their max limit).

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($customer_limit); $i++) {
    foreach ($values_array as $k => $value) {   
        $pre_existing = isset($customer[$i]) ? array_sum($customer[$i]) : 0; // If customer has any previous value, calculate the sum, or else make it 0(for the first time).
        if (($pre_existing+$value) <= $customer_limit[$i]) {  // Existing value + the current value must be less than the specified customer limit
            $customer[$i][] = @$value;    // Values are stored
            unset($values_array[$k]);    // Currently used value is deleted from the original array, considering the value used by one customer can't be used by any other customer.
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer);
```

Details of three customers:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => 50
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => 150
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => 100
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 100
        [4] => 50
    )

  )
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for...how can we display it as in a table form

Comment: can u solve these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352525/distribute-array-value-in-table-column