# Distribute array value in table column

Tags: php, loops

I have three column having limit of certain percentage of total.i want to distribute an array of values to three columns in such a manner first check customer 1 then 2 then 3 and start from customer 3,2,1 and again from 1,2,3 etc. And also check each value not crossing column limit.Remaining array value should be distribute in column having large percentage assigned.

```
Array : $stone_doll_inner_arr = array(1=>'67212','37256','32909','29847','28529','27643','25356','25274','23604','23058','18581');
```

I tried like

Table

```
for($m=1;$m<=1;$m++){


    for($n=1;$n<=count($stone_doll_inner_arr);$n++){    

        if ($n % 2 == 0) {
        $asc_desc = 'asc';
        }else{
        $asc_desc = 'desc';
        }


        //Query
        $sql_main_table = "select * from create_nemix_tbl where create_id = '".$getid."' order by percentage ".$asc_desc."";
        $qry_main_table = $con->query($sql_main_table);
        $num_main_table = $qry_main_table->num_rows;

        if ($n % 2 == 0) {
            $l = $num_main_table-1;

        }else{
            $l = 0;

        }


        while($row_main_table = $qry_main_table->fetch_array()){


                $stone_doll_val = $stone_doll_arr[$m];
                $stone_doll_val_perc = ($stone_doll_val * $row_main_table['percentage']) / 100;

                $pre_existing = isset($customer[$l]) ? array_sum($customer[$l]) : 0;
                $first_value = $pre_existing+$stone_doll_inner_arr[$n];

                $var = 0;
                if ($first_value <= $stone_doll_val_perc){

                        $customer[$l][] = $stone_doll_inner_arr[$n];
                        unset($stone_doll_inner_arr[$n]);
                        $var =1;
                }
                if($var == 1){
                    break;
                }   

        }



        if ($n % 2 == 0) {
            $l--;
        }else{
            $l++;
        }

    }

}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer);
```

Table Structure and output of script i wanted
[image]

[image]